# Filter rows if value in one column exists in another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, filter, exists

I have following table in Postgres 11:

```
col1   col2            col3               col4   
1      trial_1         ag-270              ag
2      trial_2         ag                  ag
3      trial_3         methotexate (mtx)   mtx
4      trial_4         mtx                 mtx
5      trial_5         hep-nor-b           nor-b
```

I would like to search each value of col4 throughout the column col3. If the value in col4 exists in col3, I would like to keep the rows else the row should be excluded.

Desired output is:

```
col1   col2            col3               col4   
1      trial_1         ag-270              ag
2      trial_2         ag                  ag
3      trial_3         methotexate (mtx)   mtx
4      trial_4         mtx                 mtx
```

I could not try anything on this as I am unable to find a solution to this yet.

Comment: Why is the last row (the one with `col1 = 5`) excluded? `'nor-b'` is a substring of `'hep-nor-b'`.

Comment: nor-b is not present in 'col3' as a complete string (present as a substring)

Comment: Yes it is, `'nor-b'` (`col4`) are the last (5) characters of `'hep-nor-b'` (`col3`).

Comment: Or do you mean (full) equality? But then only the row with `col1 = 2` and `col1 = 4` should be in the result.

Comment: yes, i mean full equality

Comment: As said already the your sample result doesn't make sense. But then it's simply `... WHERE col3 = col4 ...`.

Answer (score 0):

> If the value in `col4` exists in `col3`, I would like to keep the rows.

... translates to:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM tbl b WHERE b.col3 = a.col4);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d83dfc52bc0484d9caeed768eff9a89c)*

Produces your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as an inner join:

```
select distinct t.col1, t.col2, t.col3, t,col4
from T t inner join T t2 on t2.col3 = t.col4
```

Answer (score -1):

```sql
select a.*
from myTable a
where exists (
    select 1
    from myTable b
    where b.col3 = a.col4)
```

If your table has many rows, you should ensure that `col3` is indexed.